# Como colocar Limite de caracteres no Text (script)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Gostaria de limitar o texto que aparece para o usuario...eu utilizo o **InputField** para o usuario escrever o texto ,e faço o texto final receber o texto do InputField... 
*(queria adicionar reticências ( ... ) no final do texto também,indicando continuidade).*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem sempre um tamanho fixo esse campo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos montar um método de extensão que faz isso e pode ser chamado mais facilmente

```
// Recebe texto e o tamanho máximo da string
public static string Truncar(this string texto, int max)
{
    // Checa se o tamanho do texto é menor ou igual ao tamanho maximo
    // Se for menor, vai retornar apenas o texto
    // Se for maior, vai cortar a string com base na quantidade de caracteres e acrescentar o '...'
    return texto.Length <= max? texto: texto.Substring(0, max) + "...";
}

// Define tamanho máximo
int max = 10;
// Chama método de extensão passando a quantidade máxima como parâmetro
string textoTruncado = texto.Truncar(max);
```

Comment: Não responda apenas com código. Tente explicar o seu raciocínio para que seja de fácil compreensão por qualquer leitor.

Comment: Tem razão, @Isac, falha minha não ter comentado o código. Resposta atualizada

Comment: Boa resposta. Só pra referência, em inglês isso se chama "*ellipsis*" (por exemplo, no Windows Forms [tem até propriedade pra fazer isso automaticamente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis(v=vs.110).aspx)). Eu só sugiro definir um valor default pra variável `max`, assim quem chama `texto.Truncar` não precisa necessariamente passar o valor máximo. Outro detalhe **ainda mais importante** é explicar o que é extensão. O AP pode não saber que precisa salvar esse código com assinatura específica. Já te dei meu +1, mas por favor melhore essa parte, ok?

Comment: Referências sobre métodos de extensão: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) e [2](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods).

Comment: @LuizVieira vou ler essa documentação que você indicou e montar uma resposta mais completa, obrigado pelo feedback =)